# Automatic type assignment during deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net, .net-core

I have a generic model called Message that has a string called route and a payload. What the payload actually is dependant on the route. So for instance `if(Route == "Subscribe")` then payload is the subscribe model. `if(Route == "Post")` then payload has the Post model. Is there anyway I can deserialize to a generic Message model like this:

```
class Message<T> {
    string Route { get; set; }

    T PayLoad { get; set; }
}
```

And my deserialization function creates Message correctly based on the route?

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm

Comment: See [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182).